# Use terminal to copy entire folder to new nested path

Tags: terminal, path, copy, cp

I am trying to copy a folder and its contents using the terminal. The destination path does not necessarily exist. For instance;

The folder i want to copy lies at `./my-folder` and i want to copy it to `./folder-a/folder-b/folder-c/folder-d/<--put it here!-->`.

Assume folder- a, b, c and d does not exist.

I have tried using `cp -R`, `cp -a` and `cp -f` without success.

I get the error  `No such file or directory`.

I am on macOS Monterey, using z-shell.

How can i make the copy?

Comment: Edit question to, show us what you tried: if you don't then we can not tell you what you did wrong. All we can do is re-iterate the manual.

Comment: Have you tried making the missing directories `mkdir -p './folder-a/folder-b/folder-c/folder-d/'`?

Comment: I know it is possible to use mkdir, but I was really looking for a one command solution. But thank you!

Comment: that is what scripts and shell functions are for: add a shell function to `~/.bashrc` or a script to `~/bin/`.